# Visual Studio 2022 C/C++ Can not collapse if/else/while statements but can collapse functions

Tags: visual-studio-2022, outline, folding

I'm not sure why this is not working.  I've installed a fresh version of windows and freshly installed visual studio.  I can no longer collapse if/else/while statements but I can collapse functions.

I'm loosing my mind as I can not find the setting for this...  Was it removed?

Comment: The setting for it was not removed.  Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > View > Outlining > "Outline Statement Blocks" = True.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem if that didn't help.

Comment: Guess I should note... I repaired visual studio via the installer and it fixed it...  I also never saw the Outline Statement Blocks setting prior to repairing.